# О сборнике "Пословицы русского народа" В. Даля

Tags: пословицы

«Пословицы русского народа» — сборник фраз малых жанров фольклора, составленный В. И. Далем в середине XIX века. Содержит около **32 000 пословиц**, поговорок и метких слов по **178 темам**.

**Вопросы**

1. **Насколько  объективно составлен  сборник пословиц**, могли ли в нем отразиться политические взгляды автора? Почему в СССР Даля долгое время не издавали и считали "великодержавным шовинистом". В чём заключается его "великодержавный шовинизм"?
2. **Насколько сейчас актуален этот сборник?** Все ли пословицы полезны для чтения,  всегда ли они учат нас хорошему и доброму, может быть, для них нужна цензура? Как известно, после составления сборника в 1859 году Даль несколько лет не мог добиться цензурного разрешения на публикацию.
3. Существуют ли **научные труды**, посвященные исследованию и **толкованию** пословиц Даля?

Comment: Шолохов писал: " Издание русских пословиц, собранных на протяжении нескольких десятилетий прошлого века диалектологом и писателем В. И Далем, послужит великому и благородному делу изучения неисчерпаемых богатств нашей отечественной культуры и могучего языка нашего".

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос" Насколько сейчас актуален этот сборник? ".

Comment: Ответить на ваш вопрос в поле ответа я не могу, ответ слишком объемистый получится. Могу лишь сказать одно: в сборник, как пишет сам Даль, попали только те пословицы, поговорки, которые были в народе. Т. е. он отразил народную мудрость, богатство его.

Comment: Если вас интересуют подробности, могу отправить вам скриншот страниц предусловию к сборнику. Там Даль дает ответы на все вас интересующие вопросы.

Comment: Да, спасибо, мне это интересно. Значит, Даль просто записывал всё, что слышал. Но он не приводит толкования пословиц, хотя распределяет их по темам. Мог ли он ошибиться в выборе темы, а значит,  и в понимании пословицы?

Comment: Даль объясняет это так: "Я ставил, и то уже во время справы печати, самое короткое толкование, указание , где мог полагать, что это нужно для многих".  Далее он пишет: Но из не многих примеров видно, что такие объяснения. если бы собирателя и достало на них, потребовали нескольких годов времени и еще сто листов печати. Заметим, однако, что толковать и объяснять  пословицы надо крайне осторожно, чтобы не обратить этого дела в свою игрушку. Особенно опасно искать ученным взглядом того, чего бы найти хотелось...".

Comment: Куда вам можно послать скриншоты страниц? Материал на пару страниц.

Comment: Все послал. Принимайте.

Comment: Спасибо,  всё получено, попробую разобраться.